# Opencv: get/estimate camera position relative to world with different point in space

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera, geometry

For some time I have been trying to solve one of my problems:
find the position of my camera in the world space.

I have a PTZ camera that is in its space and that sends me the tilt and pan values.

I’m making six points space for the world space.

I start with my zero point of my world space, I center the point in the center of my image/screen to avoid k1 and k2. The camera returns me its tilt & pan values. And so on until my sixth point.

So my question is this: with all its data, how to find the position of my camera in the world space.

I looked to opencv; solvepnp, etc... But I didn’t find it.. Can you help me?

Thx a lot!!

Comment: do you know where these points are in 3d space?

Comment: Yes I know it. I measure them against my zero point

Comment: what you do sounds like a "[tachymeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacheometry)" or "[total station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_station)". if you investigate those things, I'm sure you'll encounter the math involved.